# REST - creating business resources

Tags: rest

In the scope of a company's payroll system, let's assume there is a PERSON resource and EMPLOYEE is a special case of it. Is is acceptable to do:

```
POST /api/v1/employees 
{
personId = 1, //existing Person
salary = 19,
departmentId = 2
}
```

This enhances the existing person making it an Employee.

In this case, would it be acceptable to refer to the employee using the person's original ID:

`GET /api/v1/employees/1` ?

Comment: Reffering is fine. But generally Id's should not be exposed

Comment: @Aashish How wold you refer to it without exposing an ID?

Comment: I work on rails, Here we generally change/customize the routes like from "GET /api/v1/employees/1" to " /api/v1/employees". So ID's are not exposed

Comment: @Aashish What if you want to get the employee with the ID 1?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a Person class and an Employee which extends from Person. Employee will have more fields like salary, department ID etc as you mentioned in the JSON.

Do you have another endpoint to access Persons? like `GET /api/v1/persons/1` ?

Or all the accessing is through `GET /api/v1/employees/1` ?

Its okay to use the same id as far as it's an extension of the first. I guess you might be using same table for storing both and thats the reason this use case arises.

**An example of using inherited resources and can use a single endpoint with a @type in resource to identify them.**

PersonResource (Considering this as Base Class)
    EmployeeResource (Extended from EmployeeResource)

For Employee Resource:

```
{
    "someOtherElement": "value",
    "person" : {
                    "@type" : "EmployeeResource",
                    "faxNumber" : "35635636",
                    "email" : "test@gmail.com",
                    "phone" : "2503334444",
                    "contactName" : "name",
                    "firstName" : "Owner",
                    "lastName" : "lastName"
                    ...
                    "address" : {
                      "@type" : "InternationalAddressResource",
                      "province" : "AB",
                      "country" : "Canada",
                      ...
                    }
                }
}
```

For IndividualResource:

```
{
    "someOtherElement": "value",
    "person" : {
                    "@type" : "PersonResource",
                    "email" : "test@gmail.com",
                    "firstName" : "Owner",
                    "lastName" : "lastName"
                    ...
                    "address" : {
                      "@type" : "PostalAddressResource",
                      "province" : "AB",
                      "country" : "Canada",
                      ...
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the Persons endpoint remains, and in this case it would return data relevant to that individual as a person, not as an employee.

Comment: Usually there will be a @type attribute adding to the resource to identify which type it is. Updating the answer with an example. It might help.